# Как сделать так чтобы данные для задачи можно было вводить через консоль, а не через код?

Tags: c, структуры

> в множестве точек A1 в трехмерном пространстве найти пару точек с максимальным расстоянием между ними

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 
 typedef struct POINT_3D
 {
   double x, y, z;
 } point_3d;
 
 double quad_distance( const point_3d *a, const point_3d *b ) 
 {
    double X = a->x - b->x;
    double Y = a->y - b->y;
    double Z = a->z - b->z;
    return ( X*X  + Y*Y + Z*Z );
 }
 
 void max_distance_points( point_3d P[], int n )
 {
    double max_dist = 0.0;
    int I = 0, J = 0;
        for ( int i = 0; i < n; ++i )
            for ( int j = i + 1; j < n; ++j )
            {
              double dist = quad_distance( &P[i], &P[j] );
                 if ( max_dist < dist )
                 { 
                    max_dist = dist;
                    I = i;
                    J = j; 
                 } 
            }    
   printf( "(%f, %f, %f) \n", P[I].x, P[I].y, P[I].z ); 
   printf( "(%f, %f, %f) \n", P[J].x, P[J].y, P[J].z );
 }
    
 int main( void ) 
 {
    point_3d points[] = { {1, 0, 4 }, {1, -3, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 2 } };
    const int n = sizeof( points ) / sizeof( points[0] ); 
    max_distance_points( points, n );
    return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Вы хотите ввести с клавиатуры 12 чисел, которые в программе в массиве `point_3d_points[]`? Если да, то можно использвать, например, scanf

Comment: Проблема заключается в том, что я не знаю как написать так чтобы 3 числа считало за 1 точку и т.д.

Comment: `scanf("%lf %lf %lf", &points[i].x, &points[i].y, &points[i].z);`  чтение 3-х чисел точки `i`